# Calculate sum with mathematical indunction

Tags: c++11

In for function, how do I number from 2 to 2. I mean `for(i=1; i<=n; i++)`. At i++ it adds 1 but how to add 2? I tried 30 minutes to make that but I can't. I tried `for(i=; i<=n; i= i+2)` or `i+=2`. I tried to add `i+1` in for function but nothing worked. How to do that?

```
$
 int sum = 1;


for(int i=1; i<=n ; i+=2) {
    sum = sum + i;
}   

return sum;


or {
    int sum = 1;

for(int i=1; i<=n ; i= i +2) {
    sum = sum + i;
}   

return sum;
```

Comment: Both see correct. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is .. i have to do a mathematical induction exercise .. and i need : if n is 1 , then 1  | if n is 3 then 1 + 3 + 5 | if n = 5 then 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 .. something like this .. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a extra variable in your for-loop

look here

```
int sum = 1, addValue= 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++n. addValue += 2)
  sum += addValue; 

return sum;
```